# Using a cut-point to break a homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, elementary-set-theory, algebraic-topology, topological-groups

How would I go about using the fact that having a cut-point is a topological property to show that $ \mathbb{R} ,\mathscr{U} \rightarrow \mathbb{R},\mathscr{C} $ is not a homeomorphism where $ \mathscr{U} $ is the usual topology on $ \mathbb{R} $, given by $ \mathscr{U}  = \{U | x \in U \rightarrow x \in (a,b) \subseteq U\} $ and $ \mathscr{C} = \{\emptyset \} \cup \{(a,\infty) | a \in \mathbb{R} \} \cup \{\mathbb{R} \} $ is the open half-line topology.

Answer (score 2):

Why use cut points? Clearly R = usual R is Hausdorff while H =   open
half line R is not Hausdorff.  Hence R and H aren't homeomorphic.

If you must use cutpoints, assume f:H -> R is homeomorphism.
R' = R - {f(x)} is disconnected;  H' = H - {x} is connected.
g = f restricted to H' is continuous surjection onto R'.

Comment: Shouldn't that be H -> U. Why is R being used?

Comment: What difference does it make. @Overflow2341313

Comment: Clarity as the main difference for anyone reading this in the future.

Comment: U is a topology and continuous functions are not between topologies but spaces.  To be clear write (R,U).